# Analyzing GIS/map data in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, api, geolocation, gis

I recently inherited a project that uses GIS mapping data to define "zones" bases on latitude/longitude coordinates. I was given almost zero background information about what I was working with. Basically I was given a folder containing several of the following file types:

- .sbn
- .sbx
- .shp
- .shx
- .mxd

And I was told to see what I can make of them. So I assume I can interact with them through .NET, but I don't know anything about any available APIs that can do what I need to do.

Here's what I have, and what I need to be able to do:

- I have the GIS files, which contain mapping data, presumably consisting of lines that define "zones", and the latitude and longitude coordinates of the lines.
- I need to be able to query the data by latitude/longitude

Can anyone suggest an API that can do this? I know this question is probably on the line as far as a good fit for this site, but I think it's probably general enough to fit.

---

### TL;DR:

Can anyone suggest a .NET api for GIS data queries?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty great API that I've used to work with SHP files.

Check out http://shapefile.codeplex.com/

Also check out MapWindow, it's a GIS tool written in .Net that comes in handy a lot.

http://www.mapwindow.org/

If you're looking for a paid API, check out ThinkGeo, they have some good .Net APIs for working with GIS data.

Answer (score 0):

These files are Esri Shp Files. The .mxn i dont know. usually all 4 or 5 files together represent geographic vector data.
search for key words "shape file reader"
(i only  know libs for java)

Answer (score 0):

First, these files are ESRI Shapefile. The mxd is arcmap project/map file, which contain the path of these gis data.

Second, you need to query these data by a `lat/lon` point. I recommend the 
[nettopologysuit](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite) library to handle spatial analysis problem.

Here is some pseudocode:

```
var shapefile=new shapefile("XXX");
//pointToEnv offset depends on your data
double offset=0.0001;
var queryZoom= new envolope(point.x-offset,point.y- 
offset,point.x+offset,point.y+offset);
//spatial query
var queryFeatures= shapefile.queryByEnvolope(queryZoom);
//tranverse your result and get what you need.
```